# i am trying to destroy a window through a def funtion to another but i keep getting this error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

when ever I click register it come up with this error

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'destroy'
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work i've tried every thing.
the aim of my program for now is that when I run the program it starts with a login screen and if I click sign up it will close the window be going to the log_to_reg definition where it says login_screen and open register_screen

```
    #importing moduels
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk

def login_screen():
    #adding the login screen
    login_screen = Tk()
    login_screen.geometry("400x250")
    login_screen.title("Tree Road School server")
    login_screen.resizable(False,False)
    login_screen.configure(background = "Light blue")
#adding the title label
label_title = Label(login_screen, text="LOGIN", width = '6',
                    font=('Arial', 25)).place(x=135, y= 25)

#adding the labels for loging in
label_username = Label(login_screen, text = "username: ", font=(15))\
                 .place(x=100, y= 100)
label_username1 = Label(login_screen, text = "       ", font=(15), width='13')\
                 .place(x=175, y= 100)

label_space = Label(login_screen, text = "          ", font=(15), width='13')\
                 .place(x=100, y= 120)
label_space1 = Label(login_screen, text = "       ", font=(15), width='13')\
                 .place(x=175, y= 120)

label_password = Label(login_screen, text = "password:  ", font=(15))\
                 .place(x=100, y= 130)
label_password1 = Label(login_screen, text = "       ", font=(15), width='13')\
                 .place(x=175, y= 130)

#adding the entry
username = Entry(login_screen, width = 15, bg = "White")
username.place(x=200, y=102)

#space to make it look nicer
password = Entry(login_screen, width = 15, bg = "White", show = "*")
password.place(x=200, y=132)

#adding the buttons
login_button = Button(login_screen, text = "login",
                      width = 10).place(x=100, y=175)

sign_up_button = Button(login_screen, text = "Register", 
                      width = 14, command = log_to_reg).place(x=190, y=175)

#run mainloop
login_screen.mainloop()

def register_screen():
    register_screen = Tk()
    register_screen.geometry("400x250")
    register_screen.title("Register")
    register_screen.resizable(False,False)
    register_screen.configure(background = "Light blue")

def log_to_reg():
    login_screen.destroy()
    rigister_screen()



login_screen()
```

Comment: You cannot have a function and a window both named `login_screen`.

Comment: Move everything between label_title through the definition of `log_to_reg` to an extra level of indentation.

Comment: Your use of place is very messy. You can get the same results in a cleaner example with pack or grid.

Comment: @jasonharper well actually you can. It is just a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your error:

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'destroy'

You have a function named `login_screen` and you are attempting to call `destroy()` on that function so it throws an error.

This is partly because you named your function and the root window the same thing. The other part is because the root window is only a local variable within the function so functions outside of the `login_screen` function cannot see the tkinter instance inside.

You could use global to manage stuff like this but all and all that is not the best option. You really want to avoid using `Tk()` more than once in tkinter and avoid the use of `global`.

Instead we can set up each item as a class and use tkinters `Toplevel()` to open the register window.

Here is a modified version of your code using `grid()` to manage everything in the window. We can also use `withdrow()` and `deiconify()` to manage what windows are visible.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Login(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry("400x250")
        self.title("Tree Road School server")
        self.resizable(False,False)
        self.configure(background = "Light blue")
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

        center_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        center_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")

        tk.Label(center_frame, text="LOGIN", width = '6', font=('Arial', 25)).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=5)
        tk.Label(center_frame, text="username: ", font=(15)).grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
        tk.Label(center_frame, text="password: ", font=(15)).grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)

        self.username = tk.Entry(center_frame, width=15, bg="White")
        self.username.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)
        self.password = tk.Entry(center_frame, width=15, bg="White", show="*")
        self.password.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)

        tk.Button(center_frame, text="login", width=10).grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
        tk.Button(center_frame, text="Register", width=14, command=self.atempt_register).grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)
        self.mainloop()

    def atempt_register(self):
        self.withdraw()
        RegisterScreen(self, self.username.get(), self.password.get())



class RegisterScreen(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, controller, username, password):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.controller = controller
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_close)
        self.geometry("400x250")
        self.title("Register")
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.configure(background = "Light blue")
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

        tk.Label(self, text=username).grid(row=0, column=0)
        tk.Label(self, text=password).grid(row=1, column=0)

    def on_close(self):
        self.controller.deiconify()
        self.destroy()


Login()
```